# display image in custom page in admin grid through image name

Tags: magento2

hello everyone i have image name in my admin grid through that i want to display the image in custom page in admin grid below code is for image name

```
<field name="customization_attachment">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Attachment</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_attachment</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magneto_PopupQuestion/image-preview</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```